# Mathematical sign as function parameter

Tags: swift

Can I somehow send the mathematical sign (+, -, *) as function parameters? I want to call `reduce()` function for different sign.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In swift signs are functions name for a specified mathematic operation. To pass sign as parameter the parameter type must be function that takes two numbers and return a number. If you command + click on any sign you will see its definition as follow :

> public func +(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
>
> public func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
>
> public func +(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
>
> public func +(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
>
> public func +(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
>
> public func +(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
>
> public func +(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
>
> public func +(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
>
> public func +(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
>
> public func +(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int

In your case your reduce function should look as the following one

```
func reduce(sign: (Int,Int)->Int) -> Int{

    return sign(2,3)
}

reduce(*)
reduce(-)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
func doSomeCalculation(_ fun:((Int, Int) -> Int)) -> Int {
    return fun(12,13)
}

doSomeCalculation(+) // 25
doSomeCalculation(-) // -1
```

The same can be done for `UInt`, the `IntXX`, etc.

`+` is basically simply a function that takes two arguments and returns the sum of it. Since `func`tions are objects like any other you can pass them around as such.

The same way you can pass `+` into `reduce`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can send any binary operator to the `reduce()` function, providing the original value and the elements in the collection are of the same type, and thus the operator can be applied.

Think at operators as functions/closures and you'll understand why this is possible in Swift. In fact operators are just like functions - they are named closures.

Also think at the way new operators can be added - you define a function with the operator name that takes a number of parameters equal to the operator arity.

Thus, the following is syntactically correct, and provides the expected output (`6`):

```
[1,2,3].reduce(0, combine: +)
```

Answer (score -3):

Send as a Character, then switch to identify:

```
func acceptASign(sign: Character) {
    switch sign {
    case "+":
        //do some addition
    case "-":
        //do some subtraction
    case "*":
        //do some multiplication
    case "/":
        //do some division
    default:
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's ok, but so clumsy : (